# When does script added with RegisterStartupScript() execute?

Tags: javascript, .net, dom, dom-events

When does script added to the page with [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) actually run? MSDN states "when the page finishes loading but before the page's `OnLoad` event is raised" but this isn't much detail.

For example, can a script added with `RegisterStartupScript` assume the DOM tree has been built? Does the behaviour differ between different browser implementations and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The startup scripts are added to the bottom of the markup. So they are processed automatically as the markup loads. I guess the exact implementation of this depends on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM tree should be built when the startup scripts are executed.